# Mysql query to retrieve single image from an array of images?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

**Table to store array of Images:**

```
`products` and  `products_photos`

`products` includes only `id` field
`products_photos` includes `product_id` and `filename`
```

**Table values:**

```
products 
-------- 
id-6

id-7


products_photos
---------------
6 - filename1

6 - filename2

7 - filename3
```

In these two table **id 6** includes 2 images but i need to fetch only one image from that. How to write a query for that in mysql or laravel.

Comment: please provide some code you already tried

Comment: provide some of your code.

Comment: And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the latest (last added) image of the product then you can do the following way

NOTE : Instead of *, use the precise columns so that your query performs faster.

```
SELECT * FROM products_photos WHERE product_id = 6 ORDER BY products_photos.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to get the first (old added) image of the product then you can do the following way

```
SELECT * FROM products_photos WHERE product_id = 6 ORDER BY products_photos.id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

**Updated :**  Query to get the list of all the records group

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id, photo_name FROM products_photos GROUP BY photo_name
```

In case if you have more than one columns and want to get the latest record for that too then go for this

Eg. Considering that your having **description** column and want to get the MAX (latest) content than use MAX, if you need oldest use MIN

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id, photo_name, MAX(description) as description FROM products_photos GROUP BY photo_name
```

Comment: But I want to get the images for all the productid's not for specified id

Comment: Then in that case remove the where condition

Comment: It just gives me a single value

Comment: I want a single image from an array of image stored using a unique id

Comment: K please wait will update my answer with the appropriate query

Comment: HI @suryakalavelusamy Please check my updated answer beneath  the actual answer

Answer (score 0):

You can give limit to your query to get single result

```
SELECT * FROM products_photos WHERE product_id = 6 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Which will give single image only for id = 6 product

For retrieve all data use `group by`

```
SELECT * FROM GemSellerPortal.products pr 
LEFT JOIN GemSellerPortal.products_photos ph
ON ph.product_id = pr.id
GROUP BY pr.id
```

Comment: without mentioning the id,how to retrieve it

Comment: because ,if id-7 also stores multiple values,then how can I able to fetch single images from both the id

Comment: why @Strawberry?

Comment: `SELECT products_photos.filename FROM GemSellerPortal.products 
LEFT JOIN GemSellerPortal.products_photos 
ON products_photos.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.id` this is my query

Comment: It throws an error,that select clause is not in GROUPBY something..]

Comment: Error Code: 1055. Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'GemSellerPortal.ph.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: what is the name of field for image ?

Comment: Here's four things to get the ball rolling. 1. You would NEVER use a GROUP BY clause in a query absent of any aggregating functions. 2. You would NEVER use a GROUP BY clause in conjunction with 'SELECT *'. 3. NEVER use 'SELECT *'. 4. LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry I have added `*` because I don't know column names. I also know use if DISTINCT but for that I also need field name. For your last suggestion I have updated first query

Comment: If you don't know the column names, my preference is to ask for clarification from the OP rather than using up precious bits of internet with junk - especially where a rep score might lead a reader to conclude that an answer was more authoritative than was actually the case.

Comment: I already ask for field name @Strawberry but no response from OP. I think I have to leave now. If OP not interested to give rep

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP would give rep where its plainly undeserved !?!

Comment: I already ask almost before an hour **what is the name of field for image ?** @Strawberry

Comment: I don't see what's meretricious about that.

Comment: You ask *why the OP would give rep where its plainly undeserved* that why I have highlighted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159228/discussion-between-strawberry-and-b-desai).